# Can I open Safari without specifying a destination URL?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mobile-safari

I just want to force the Safari (or default browser) app to the foreground **without specifying a destination URL**. Is there a custom URL that would do that?

I know there are some custom URLs in iOS to bring some of the native apps forward. I can't find one for Safari.

Comment: Please don't [delete and repost questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940415/can-i-open-safari-without-specifying-a-destination-url#23940415).

Comment: I would rather not do that either, but most responses were not valid to the question.

Comment: All you had were a handful of comments. You should edit your question to clarify it and respond to any concerns raised.

Comment: Thanks for the info Josh. I didn't see that post.